# How do I perform this arithmatic in a more elegant manner?

Tags: java

```
frequency = ((x * y)) / roomSize / roomSize
```

How do I simplify the `/ roomSize / roomSize` ?

Comment: Before we can answer, please tell us whether these variables are `int`, `double`, or something else.

Comment: Keep your pinky fingers arched up as you type.

Comment: Oh, yeah, and put on a nicer shirt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`frequency = (x * y) / (roomSize * roomSize)`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, `frequency = x * y * Math.pow(roomSize, -2)`